# Solving geetest with 2captcha in Java

Tags: java, selenium, captcha

I am attempting to bypass a geetest using 2captcha api.
https://2captcha.com/demo/geetest

I understand I need to submit the "gt" and "challenge" when trying to solve the captcha via api.

What I dont understand is how to extract this information from a website - additionally once solved
how do I go about injecting the response? I am using selenium to navigate the website.

Comment: It's somewhere in the page source. You probably need to do it from javascript.

Answer (score 2):

It should show the GT and challenge parameters in the request to geetest's domain. Picture below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GdTi.png